# How to loop over multiple files and save output using filename

Tags: r

So I have a directory with 100 files named with 100 different names. I want to perform a function on all the files in te directory, and save the new files as the original file name with _clean at the end of name. so for example, I perform the function on file A1.txt, and it becomes A1_clean.tree.
If t is each file in the directory, I need to perform :

```
tree <- read.tree(t) 
unrooted_tr <- unroot(tree)
unrooted_tr$node.label=NULL
```

these 3 lines on each file. I cant get it to work. Below is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
library(picante)

files <- list.files(path="tree/", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

lapply(files, function(x){
  t <- read.table(x, header=TRUE)
  tree <- read.tree(t) 
  unrooted_tr <- unroot(tree)
  unrooted_tr$node.label=NULL 
  out <- function(t)
  write.tree(unrooted_tr, file = t,"_clean.tree")
})
```

Comment: What is `out <- function(t)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: My guess (as I don't use `picante`, and ignoring `out <- function(t)`): `write.tree(unrooted_tr, file=paste0(x, "_clean.tree"))`

Comment: Can you be more specific on how your code isn't working? Is it throwing an error (what is the error)? Is it saving output, but the output is wrong (wrong in what way)? Does it run without errors, but nothing is saved...? Not familiar with this package, but at a glance, `out <- function(t)` is just assigning a function that's never called, and may be preventing execution of the following line.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(tools)
require(picante)


files <- list.files(path = "tree/",
                            pattern = "*.txt",
                            full.names = T,recursive = F) 

custom_fct <- function(.file){
  t <- fread(.file,header=T) # faster than read.csv
  unrooted_tr <- unroot(read.tree(t))
  unrooted_tr$node.label=NULL 
  write.tree(unrooted_tr,file=paste0(file_path_sans_ext(.file),"_clean.tree"))  
}

lapply(files,custom_fct)
```